# Horizontal mean with polars expressions

Tags: python, mean, python-polars

I need to compute row means in polars. I did not see an `axis` parameter in the documentation of `pl.Expr.mean`.

As example, consider the following dataframe.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3],
    "bar": [6, 7, 8],
})
```

How can I compute the row-wise mean here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As of polars [version 0.20.8](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.20.8), you can simply use [`pl.mean_horizontal`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.mean_horizontal.html) as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.mean_horizontal(pl.all()).alias("mean"))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ mean │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ 3.5  │
│ 2   ┆ 7   ┆ 4.5  │
│ 3   ┆ 8   ┆ 5.5  │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
     {
         "foo": [1, 2, 3],
         "bar": [6, 7, 8],
    }
)

df.with_column(
    (pl.sum(pl.all()) / 2).alias("mean")
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ mean │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ 3.5  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 7   ┆ 4.5  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 8   ┆ 5.5  │
└─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

If the horizontal aggregations get more complicated, I would recommend using `pl.fold` or `pl.reduce`.

Comment: Actually my code is more complicated also cause I have an unknown columns number and known only at runtime. I solved by passing an iterator to my function and sum with a fold and dividing by iterator len. Maybe pl.reduce could be better?